# MySQL Partition By Both DATE and INT

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning, sharding

I have a table I want to partition using MySQL 5.7 Partitioning to mitigate issues I'm having with dropping old data quickly. (Also, it would be nice to have increased insert I/O performance by partitioning across something other than date, especially if I plan to shard across multiple volumes with subpartitions)

Here is a simplified version of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cmd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code`   TINYINT DEFAULT NULL,
  `rqst`   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  UNIQUE KEY `uk1` (sub_id,cmd_id,date) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB

(note that use of column 'date' in uk1 is only to allow partitioning on date)
(The true unique key is (sub_id,cmd_id))
```

Here are the SQL statements I make on that table:

```
1. INSERT INTO tbl (NOW(), ...)
2. UPDATE tbl SET code=$code WHERE sub_id=$sub_id AND cmd_id=$cmd_id
3. SELECT code,rqst FROM tbl WHERE sub_id=$sub_id AND cmd_id=$cmd_id
```

Here is the partitioning scheme I've devised so far:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(date))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(sub_id)
SUBPARTITIONS 4
(PARTITION d001 VALUES LESS THAN (736250) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d002 VALUES LESS THAN (736260) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d003 VALUES LESS THAN (736270) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d004 VALUES LESS THAN (736280) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d005 VALUES LESS THAN (736290) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d006 VALUES LESS THAN (736300) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d007 VALUES LESS THAN (736310) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d008 VALUES LESS THAN (736320) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d009 VALUES LESS THAN (736330) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d010 VALUES LESS THAN (736340) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION d011 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

However I believe this will hurt performance by requiring a read per each partition every time i reference (sub_id,cmd_id):

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE sub_id='107' AND cmd_id='2246806';
+----+-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions                                                                                                                                     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | optz  | d001_d001sp1,d002_d002sp1,d003_d003sp1,d004_d004sp1,d005_d005sp1,d006_d006sp1,d007_d007sp1,d008_d008sp1,d009_d009sp1,d010_d010sp1,d011_d011sp1 | ref  | uk1           | uk1  | 38      | const,const |   11 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

So the crux of my problem is:

- If i partition by D date's then its D-1 Extra lookups
- If i partition by S sub_id's then I cant easily DROP partitions on Date
- I don't see how I could use COLUMNS Partitioning

Here are some notes/caveats:

- INSERTing about 5-20million rows/day
- Equal distribution of read,write,insert - but always single row
- Only need to keep past ~month of data
- A replication system is in place
- The hardware involved is expensive
- I didn't want to include the `date` column in the unique key but then I couldn't partition on it, so the code ensures (sub_id,cmd_id) is unique across dates as it stands.

Thanks!

Comment: Your comment says "month of data", but the partitions seem to be about 10*10 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BY HASH` is essentially useless, as are `SUBPARTITIONs`.

> mitigate issues I'm having with dropping old data quickly.

That is, you need to `DROP PARTITION` for old `date`?  Use `PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(date))` and don't bother with the subpartitioning.

For clarity, change `UNIQUE KEY uk1 (sub_id,cmd_id,date)` to `PRIMARY KEY (sub_id,cmd_id,date)`.

[belated edited] Your three queries will work reasonably well with such.  The `SELECT` and `UPDATE` will have to hit all partitions since `date` is not in the `WHERE` clause.  The `INSERT` will hit only the latest partition (because of `NOW()`).

More discussion, including tips on doing the periodic purging: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

> Only need to keep past ~month of data

Recommend about 32 partitions -- one pending `DROP`, one `future`; see the link.

> A replication system is in place

Doing the `ALTER TABLE` to add partitioning will stall the system, but I guess you understand the issue there.

> I didn't want to include the date column in the unique key but then I couldn't partition on it, so the code ensures (sub_id,cmd_id) is unique across dates as it stands.

Yeah, a necessary evil.

> 5-20million rows/day

That's a max of a few hundred per second?  If you have ingestion speed problems, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Comment: A compromise would be to keep about 38 days -- in weekly 6 weekly partitions.  That would decrease the number partitions for `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, but increase the disk space needed, while still providing the efficiency of `DROP PARTITION`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I actually spent a couple nights reading through your website before i did this original post ;) I'm gonna update this comment with a question about your answer after i get a chance to read through a bit more. thanks again.